# How to stop my own udp packets flooding my own router

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I think I know the answer and that answer is 'no I cannot'. But in case I am missing a trick..

I have a web app.  I create a byte array of say 2K byes and send 10 of these every second to my signalR Hub hosts.

I have found that if my internet/LAN is slow the udp packets seemed to get bunched up and are received by my clients perhaps 3 minutes after sending them.

Now I know Udp comms are based on 'fire-and-forget' and that tcp comms would send me an ACK back for me to judge when to send the next packet.

But I am using udp packets for speed. I am not bothered if a packet is lost or even sent in the wrong order. I am just trying to avoid lag.

I have written this in C# but it could be any language I guess.  I am just after any best practice. I do not think my code is relevant. But, if required I will of course post it up here.

What I prefer to happen is to 'purge/drop' any packets if there is a 'queue'.

I appreciate people may wish to ask 'why do I not use TCP'. It is a long answer and a different question.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225784/discussion-on-question-by-andrew-simpson-how-to-stop-my-own-udp-packets-flooding).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be an ICMP Source Quench, where an upstream device would send "source quenches" to a host to tell it to slow down.  This was deprecated some time ago but is something similar to what you are looking for.

The only way to do this is going to be to independently monitor your routers bandwidth and internal queues via some out-of-band means (eg SNMP) and if some thresholds are met then back off sending the packets.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I have manually done what the above did and it works fine Not sure why they took it out. They should at least make it optional. Thanks for confirming my brilliant idea :)